# What is the calling method of validateForm callback of a FormInterface subclass

Tags: forms

i just want to know where in the drupal code the validateForm method is called from the FormBuilder.

In the doValidateForm of FormValidator class i don't see the callback being called !

Can you give me some hints?

Answer (score 2):

It's not called directly. When preparing a form build array the FormBuilder adds it as #validate callback

*FormBuilder::prepareForm()*

```
$form['#validate'][] = '::validateForm';
$form['#submit'][] = '::submitForm';
```

which is then executed later like any other validate or submit callback.

Comment: Thanks a lot! it helps!